# Track the path of current page

Tags: asp.net

i want to know that from which pages my current page has been called in ASP.net

As for example

I want the track of page named "hero.aspx" and it has been called from "Zero.aspx"
and "Zero.aspx" has been called from "one.aspx"

So i want output as whole page called hierarchy.

How can i get this in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
HttpRequest.UrlReferrer
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get the referring page from

VB:

```
 Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
```

C#

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

If you want the path I think you will have to save each page coming to it in session and then append each page to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Region "Properties"

        Public Property prevPage() As String
            Get
                If Not ViewState("prevPage") Is Nothing Then
                    Return CType(ViewState("prevPage"), String)
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                ViewState("prevPage") = Value
            End Set
        End Property

#End Region

If Not IsPostBack Then

   If Not Request.UrlReferrer Is Nothing Then
       prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
   End If 

 End If
```